# Set AngularJS directives to DOM node from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The idea that I'm trying to reproduce is to set the angular directive('ng-show') from the controller.

I try to do the next:

```js
var node = `<div ng-show="this.length > 5">...</div>`;
var child = document.createElement('span');
child.innerHTML = node;
document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(child);
```

Is it proper way to set the directive on DOM Node before one is being added to the DOM Tree?

Comment: You need to compile the node variable using $compile

Comment: It does not cover the case, when the length is the binding from parent component.
Can you suggest realization for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$compile` service of AngularJS to add the HTML with angular directives dynamically in the HTML page like this

```
app_module.controller('appController', function ($scope, $compile) {
   var node = `<div ng-show="this.length > 5">...</div>`;
   var child = document.createElement('span');
   child.innerHTML = node;
   $compile(document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(child))($scope);
});
```

The `$compile` service will re-compile the AngularJS template and detect the newly added `ng-show`.

Comment: This does not answer the question if it is a proper way to do it, just a answer to how you do it...